# "We're sorry but something went wrong please try again" when enabling testing/simulator for Smart Home action

Tags: actions-on-google

When enabling testing of my Smart Home action for an old project I get "we're sorry but something went wrong please try again" and my Smart Home action does not show up for linking in the Google Home app.

I created a new project and I can enable testing mode for it. However, I would like to use my old project as I have set up several services/APIs (like report state) that I would prefer not to set up from scratch on a new project.

Any way to know why I am getting "we're sorry but something went wrong please try again" and/or figure out what is different between my old and new projects that makes the old not work?

My old application was responding to Google Assistant commands but I had to unlink ir because re-sync'ing my smart home devices was failing. After unlinking I am not able to re-link because I cannot get my application in testing mode due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Smart home projects that have been in a test mode for a while may expire. You should be able to go to the project again in the Actions Console and disable testing by clicking on the laptop/phone icon (third icon)

[image]

Then re-enable testing by clicking on the **Start Testing** button.

[image]

Then you should be able to see it show up in the list of smart home Actions to link with.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Nick. I've tried several times the procedure that you suggest (disable/re-enable testing) but the result is always the same, i.e. "we're sorry but something went wrong please try again" after a few seconds. Could it be some setting or permission that is now applied to new projects that my old project doesn't have what is causing the problem? For example, I see additional Firebase-related service account/permissions in the IAM page of the new project (the one where I can enable testing with no issues).

Comment: Any solution for this? Same issue here.